# Java SocketException: socket is closed

Tags: java, android-studio, inputstream, httpurlconnection, socketexception

I've a big problem and I don't understand why it is so.
My problem is, when I get MediaFiles from Server (.mp4 files) and try to save it at local storage, I got an Exception: socket is closed. Please help me.

```
    try {
        RequestHelper requestHelper = new RequestHelper(activity);
        HttpURLConnection conn = requestHelper.connection(url + file, "GET");

        int statuscode = requestHelper.getStatuscode(conn);
        if (statuscode == 200) {
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("inputStream: " + is);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(saveDir, file.getName()));
            System.out.println("outputStream: " + os);



            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            
            //HERE IS THE EXCEPTION TRIGGER
            System.out.println("inputstreamRead: " + is.read(b));

            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Seems like the other side closes the socket.

Answer (score 0):

can you check if you have added keep-alive header?